# Отключение WebRTC в Selenium ChromeDriver C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, chromedriver

Как отключить WebRTC в Selenium ChromeDriver C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**И так мы имеем Selenium ChromeDriver, наша задача:**

1. отключить Flash
2. убрать сообщение в верху браузера (чтоб не раздражало)
3. подключить прокси
4. отключить WebRTC
5. и если мы используем браузер в нескольких потоках - скрыть интерфейс

**Реализация:**

```
private ChromeDriver SetUpDriver()
{
    var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; // скрываем консоль драйвера
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments($"--proxy-server={proxy}"); // утанавливаем прокси
    options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.AddArgument($"--window-size={windSise}"); // устанавливаем размер окна
    options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors"); // игнорируем ошибки сертификата
    options.AddArgument($"--user-agent={userAgent}"); // устанавливаем свой юзерагент
    options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash"); // отключаем Flash
    options.AddArgument("--headless"); // скрываем браузер 
    options.AddArguments($"load-extension={path}/extension"); // загружаем расширение

    return new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
}
```

**Как установить расширение в ChromeDriver:**
Находим и устанавливаем расширение к себе в браузер, я остановился на **WebRTC Control**, идём по пути `C:\Users\имя_пользователя\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`
находим папку с нашим расширением, и копируем в папку приложения, для последующей сборки.
**Редактирование JS** этот шаг необходим чтоб при загрузке не открывалась домашняя страница WebRTC Control в браузере.
Путь к файлу `path\extension\версия\lib\chrome\chrome.js` открываем файл находим и комментируем строки:

```
//app.tab = {"open": function (url) {chrome.tabs.create({"url": url, "active": true})}};
//if (chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL) chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL(app.homepage() + "?v=" + app.version() + "&type=uninstall", function () {});
```

Сохраняем файл запускам браузер - радуемся жизни.

P/s будет время ещё к Вам заскочу на огонёк.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю что самым простым из путей будет создать профиль с отключенным WebRTC и просто запускать селениум напрямую с этим профилем браузера.

Если найдешь плагин который отключает его (Extensions: WebRTC Network Limiter, WebRTC Control, WebRTC Leak Prevent)...

Но нужно иметь ввиду, что вполне возможно, что в хроме сейчас это вообще невозможно сделать полностью - хоть с плагинами хоть без.

Лучше проверить на чем-то включен он или нет.

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю. сколько ни бился другого решения как подключить профиль + расширение для хром драйвера я не нашел. про верять можно тут : [whoer](https://whoer.net/ru)

Comment: Плюс за труды, только это не работает, я даже загружал .crx - не отключает в ChromeDriver

Comment: Ну я не просто так написал `Но нужно иметь ввиду, что вполне возможно, что в хроме сейчас это вообще невозможно сделать полностью.`. Такая информация мне встретилась, но я не знал на сколько она вообще актуальна т.к. была запощена пару лет назад -- за такое время могло что-то и изменится.

Comment: @Digital Core Как вариант, использовать Firefox, если это возможно, там WebRTC отключается одним параметром

Comment: думаю, это плохой вариант, если человек напрямую спрашивает именно о ChromeDriver :)

Comment: У меня получилось отключить при помощи расширения WebRTC, работает   100%, позже если будет время опубликую, так как говорил ранее через загрузку расширения, пришлось подкорректировать Js расширения .